How did {irrationals} become bigger than {rationals}?
There exists an irrational number between any two rational numbers and there exists a rational number
between any two irrational numbers.
Then why cardinality of irrationals are greater than that of rationals?

What's the smallest irrational number greater than $\frac{1}{2}$? What's the next rational number after $\pi$?

Why not try to define the bijection you have in mind?  Hand waving about what ought to be possible won't get you very far.

"matching any rational to the upper limit of the irrational interval or vice-versa." The upper limit of which irrational interval?

One issue is that the (ir)rationals involved need not be unique.
You suppose there exists a rational between $-\pi$ and $\pi$; well, $1$ meets that criterion.
And likewise a rational between $-\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 2$; well, $1$ also meets that criterion.
So, if we have a claimed bijection $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ defined by the property...

"If $a,b$ are irrational with $a<b$, then there is a rational $r \in (a,b)$. Define $f(r) := b$."

...then what is $f(1)$? Is it $\pi$? $\sqrt 2$?
This function is ill-defined.

I suppose you want something like this. Knowing the rationals are countable, we can list them in an orderly fashion as:
$$\mathbb{Q}= \{q_1, q_2, \dots\}.$$
Now define a function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ as
$$f(q)= \max\{r \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} : r<q\}.$$
We cannot take supremum, because the least upper bound of the set $\{r \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} : r<q\}$ is $q$ itself, a rational.
So as pointed out in the other answer, which irrational do we take as a representative from the set? And if we do that successfully, we will end up with a bijection from rationals to a countable subset of the irrationals. Which we know is wrong since irrationals are uncountable
